# How to send every row to an API and store the result in a new column via python?

Tags: python, pandas, api

I have a dataframe (`testdata`) of 1 column with n rows that each contain a string. I want to send all to an API and store the result in the next column. But the API where I can send lists to analyze something  (like `["Test1"],["Test2"]`) has a limit of 20 elements per call, that's why i wanted to write a function that for each row/cell sends the string element (`doc`) to the API and stores the result in a new column via the apply-function.

```
testdata
def API(doc):
    result = APIclient.analyze(doc, language="en")
    return result
API(["Test1"],["Test2"])
#testdata["Response"] = testdata.apply(API, axis = 1)
```

Right now, the function works if applied to lists like here (`API(["Test1"],["Test2"])`) but if i want to apply it to every row my column i get the typical `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`-error. Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: This code doesn't work: `TypeError: API() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`. Please make a [mre] including working code as well as some example data and desired output. That'll require making some equivalent of `APIclient.analyze` for testing purposes. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341) for specifics.

Comment: Oh wait, I just realized you're doing `testdata.apply`, not `testdata[column].apply`, which means `doc` is a row (`Series`), not a string.

Answer (score 0):

Rows and cells are not interchangeable. A row is a vector (`Series`), while a cell is a scalar (usually). It looks like the error is happening because `APIclient.analyze()` expects a string, not a `Series`.

Simply replace `testdata.apply` with either:

- `testdata[column].apply` - by column name
- `testdata.iloc[:, 0].apply` - by column number (0)